# ¿Cuál es la función sintáctica de "me" in "me temo que[...]"?

Tags: verbos, sintaxis, morfología

Tengo una ligera confusión sobre la naturaleza y la función del pronombre "me" en la oración "***me temo que el agua fresca no sea la mejor solución***"

1. ¿Es "temerse" un verbo reflexivo o un verbo pronominal? No entiendo muy bien la diferencia entre los dos. ¿Existe un truco práctico para distinguir uno del otro? Según [esta pagina](http://elblogdegramatica.blogspot.com/2013/07/verbos-pronominales-reflexivos-y.html), "*Para reconocer si ese se es reflexivo, hay que agregar al final de la oración a sí mismo. Si el significado de la oración no cambia, el se es reflexivo.*" Dado que no se puede decir "temo a mí mismo que el agua fresca no  sea una buena solución", supongo que *temerse* no es un verbo reflexivo. Mi mejor suposición es que sea un verbo pronominal y por lo tanto exige que el pronombre sea objeto indirecto o directo
2. [Según la página Wikipedia sobre los verbos pronominales](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbo_pronominal#:%7E:text=Un%20verbo%20reflexivo%20es%20aquel,adem%C3%A1s%20carece%20de%20funci%C3%B3n%20sint%C3%A1ctica.), el pronombre de los verbos pronominales funciona como complemento directo/indirecto y el de los verbos reflexivos carecen de función sintáctica. Tomo esta última información con dudas.
3. ¿Entonces, por nuestro ejemplo, cuál es la naturaleza y la función sintáctica de "me"? ¿Qué tipo de verbo es "temerse" ?

Answer (score 1):

El verbo "temerse" es un verbo pronominal donde el pronombre simplemente es marca del verbo pronominal y carece de cualquier función sintáctica.

Antiguamente, se los solía llamar "verbos cuasirreflejos".

Otros ejemplos son *reírse, olvidarse, caerse.*

Comment: tenéis un truco para distinguir los verbos pronominales de los verbos reflexivos ?

Comment: La técnica consistiría en agregar "a mí/ti/sí mismo" como propusiste. Si el verbo lo acepta, es reflexivo. Si no, es pronominal.

Comment: disculpa para estar minucioso, pero ¿será invalida la oración "Temo a mí mismo que no sea la mejor solución"? 
En este sentido "Tengo a mi mismo por objecto de temor > me temo"
No entiendo por que no lo podriamos considerar como objecto directo

Comment: "Me temo a mí mismo" sólo sería posible si uno mismo fuera objeto de su temor. En cambio, en tu oración lo que se teme no es a uno mismo sino que el agua fresca no sea la mejor solución.

Comment: 1) ¿No se podría tomar dos objetos el verbo ? Así "Temo "a mí mismo"(O.D) "que no sea la mejor solución" (O.D)"
2) Que piensa sobre la interpretación que la función de "me" sea un dativo aspectual ?
http://gramaticaespanola.com/publ/las_funciones/el_complemento_indirecto/dativo_etico_y_dativo_concordado/53-1-0-634

Comment: En "me temo (a mí mismo)", "me" es objeto indirecto, no directo. Tanto es así que si la persona temida es un tercero usamos "le", no "la" o "lo": le temo. Tampoco creo que sea un dativo aspectual, que se caracteriza por dar un sentido de completitud a la acción, por ej.: Me comí la torta (en lugar de "comí la torta"). No encuentro diferencia semántica entre "Temo que no sea la solución" y "Me temo que no sea la solución". Ergo, "me" no es un dativo.

Comment: Pensé que era un tipo de dativo aspectual como explicado en la pagina https://www.espanolavanzado.com/gramatica-avanzada/586-se-aspectual : 

"The se aspectual, however, cannot always be explained by denoting the culmination of an event. When used with predicates that are already telic (they have a limit) a commonly held view is that the se denotes agency, will or internal cause originating from the subject: Using the se tends to transport the listener and speaker to the moment of the action where they witness it in its entirety. [...]

Comment: Example given in the website : →Me imagino que habrá vida después de la muerte — I imagine there is life after death (right now; on this occasion I imagine; complete telic event viewed in its entirety; implies agency; more common in spoken Spanish)

Comment: También comparto una página del RAE sobre este subjeto : http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=bGVpPRVZFszaAtHw
En efecto, 35.7 : El dativo aspectual tiene valor enfático, En efecto, la diferencia entre Leímos toda la prensa y Nos leímos toda la prensa radica en que en la segunda opción se da a entender que hay mayor implicación del subjeto en la acción que se menciona. [...] El dativo concordado solo se combina con predicados que expresan eventos delimitados, por lo que se rechazan oraciones como *Ana se bebió leche."
Pienso que "me temo""me imagino" caen en esta clase. Que le parece?